# Regularity condition of 3rd Case of Master Theorem. Need explanation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I do not understand how regularity expression was constructed in Wiki example for 3rd Case Master Theorem. Here is what given in Wiki

[image]

Shouldn't it be $$2(\frac{n^2}{2}) \leq kn^2$$ for regularity condition?

If we have b = 2, how did we get 4 as our denominator?

Comment: I would assume that the 4 appears because it's just 2 squared like this $(\frac{n}{2})^2$ instead of $\frac{n^2}{2}$ but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @kingW3 no... nothing could be squared here as I understand. Regularity condition is just af(n/b) <= kf(n)